MoveIt2 with effort_controllers/JointGroupEffortController
Does anyone know if this is the correct setup of the MoveIt with the effort ros2 controller?

What do I want to do?

Having a custom robotic arm, I would like to control the simulated drives in my robotic arm. The controller output should be effort, not position (therefore I am not using joint trajectory group controller this time). I wanted to set the position of the eef and the controller should send effort values to the drives in order to reach the desired position. At this state, I am not even sure that this is the right approach.

What is the actual state?

My robot falls, simply it collapses. I can send effort commands through the CLI tool ros2 topic pub ... and the robot moves. This means, that the effort controller does its job.


In my ros2 controller yaml file, I got:
controller_manager:
  ros__parameters:
    update_rate: 1000  # Hz

    sensorob_group_controller:
      type: effort_controllers/JointGroupEffortController


    joint_state_broadcaster:
      type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster

sensorob_group_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    joints:
      - joint_1
      - joint_2
      - joint_3
      - joint_4
      - joint_5
      - joint_6

    state_publish_rate: 1000.0 
    action_monitor_rate: 1000.0
    allow_nonzero_velocity_at_trajectory_end: false

    command_interfaces:
      - effort
    state_interfaces:
      - position
      - velocity

    constraints:
      stopped_velocity_tolerance: 0.02 # Override default
      joint_1:
        trajectory: 0.15              
        goal: 0.005
      joint_2:
        trajectory: 0.15              
        goal: 0.005
      joint_3:
        trajectory: 0.15               
        goal: 0.005
      joint_4:
        trajectory: 0.15               
        goal: 0.005
      joint_5:
        trajectory: 0.15              
        goal: 0.005
      joint_6:
        trajectory: 0.15               
        goal: 0.005

    gains:
      joint_1: {p: 1000,   d: 10, i: 0.01, i_clamp: 1}
      joint_2: {p: 1000,   d: 10, i: 0.01, i_clamp: 1}
      joint_3: {p: 1000,   d: 10, i: 0.01, i_clamp: 1}
      joint_4: {p: 1000,   d: 10, i: 0.01, i_clamp: 1}
      joint_5: {p: 1000,   d: 10, i: 0.01, i_clamp: 1}
      joint_6: {p: 1000,   d: 10, i: 0.01, i_clamp: 1}

MoveIt controller config file:
controller_names:
  - sensorob_group_controller

sensorob_group_controller:
  type: FollowJointTrajectory
  action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
  default: true
  joints:
    - joint_1
    - joint_2
    - joint_3
    - joint_4
    - joint_5
    - joint_6

In the ros2 control xacro file, I am using Gazebo ros2 control plugin:
<plugin filename="libgazebo_ros2_control.so" name="gazebo_ros2_control">

The first joint is configured as:
<joint name="joint_1">
    <command_interface name="position"/>
    <command_interface name="effort"/>
    <state_interface name="position">
        <param name="initial_value">0.0</param>
    </state_interface>
    <state_interface name="velocity">
        <param name="initial_value">0.0</param>
    </state_interface>
    <state_interface name="effort"/>
</joint>

Both controllers (js publisher and effort controller) are configured successfully and I can see them connected as well:

This is the RViZ screenshot, the fallen robot is visualized from Gazebo:


The effort_controllers/JointGroupEffortController is not a feedback-controller, it won't maintain the position of the robot. It only forwards the effort to your robot. You would have to write a gravity compensation node (or filter) to send the correct feed-forward effort values to maintain the position.
What you probably need is a joint_trajectory_controller with effort as command interface: It has a feedback-loop, configurable with the PID gains, to maintain the position of the robot, but sends effort values to your robot.

what an informative response, I love the ROS community! Thanks. I am going with the joint_trajectory_controller with effort command_interface. My bad that I did not read the documentation properly.

You're welcome. Please just mark the question as answered (if this is the case)..
